# How to extract all peptide sequences for a UniProt protein entry with an API?

Tags: uniprot, api

I know how to generally pull down information for a UniProt entry using the REST API, for example:

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=id:Q9UJL9&sort=score&columns=id,go(molecular%20function)&format=tab

I'm looking at [this](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q9UBU3) entry as an example. I'm able to pull down most of the attributes I want with a variation of the API query above, however, I'm stuck on one part.

For all human proteins, I want to pull down the peptide sequences that come from that protein.

In the example above, it would be the sequences of the peptides associated with this section:

[image]

Can this be done with the API or do I have to come with a scraping method for all human proteins where I (1) get the protein sequence of each entry, (2) get this table, (3) calculate where the peptides start and end from the sequence in step 1?
I feel like this alternative will be much slower, so I want to check I'm not missing anything obvious.

Comment: Downloading the whole of Uniprot and filtering for humans is probably a nicer solution. It is in XML format, which is a bit of a pain, but is a goldmine of data, which you may need —totally depends on your plans and how they may _evolve_. E.g. I have written [my own Python XML Uniprot parser](https://github.com/matteoferla/MichelaNGLo-protein-module/blob/master/michelanglo_protein/generate/_protein_uniprot_mixin.py) due to my needs and I have [a human scraped dataset](https://github.com/matteoferla/MichelaNGLo-human-protein-data) that is heavily focused on my project which expanded with time.

Answer (score 1):

If downloading the complete database is not an option, you may able to use the instructions from this help page (based on the gff format for any given query):

https://www.uniprot.org/help/download_subsequences